# cigarette lighter power plug; how to wire?

Tags: soldering, wiring

The part
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mpd-memory-protection-devices/ZA1030/2439603?s=N4IgTCBcDaIF4EMCMAGAzCgtAOwCYgF0BfIA

and the drawing
https://www.memoryprotectiondevices.com/datasheets/ZA1030-datasheet.pdf

How do you wire this plug?  Is there an additional set of ferrules/supporting parts or crimping tools needed?  Solder wets fine, but will cold work.

[image]

Comment: i have opened four or five of these in the past ... they were all connected the same way ... fold wire over item 4 and solder ... solder end of wire to inside of item 1 .... some power plugs had a built-in inline fuse connected to item 1 at one end ... the wire was sodered to the other end of fuse

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is done in a commercial product (12V compressor):
[image]

So soldering it seems to be the correct way.
The minus wire is wrapped around that metal piece before soldering.